# Show selected text file from one listbox in another

Tags: c#

This is my code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    FileInfo SelectedFileInfo = (FileInfo)ListBox1.SelectedItem;

    StreamReader FileRead = new StreamReader(SelectedFileInfo.FullName);
    string CurrentLine = "";
    //int LineCount = 0;
    while(FileRead.Peek() != -1)
    {
        CurrentLine = FileRead.ReadLine();
        //LineCount++;
        //if(LineCount % 5 == 2)
        {
            ListBox2.Items.Add(CurrentLine);
        }
    }
    FileRead.Close(); 
}
```

but throws exception about:

> Cannot convert type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' to 'System.IO.FileInfo'

Comment: Why is so much of your code commented out?

Comment: What do you need out of fileinfo?  The error is correct; you can't typecast a `ListItem` to a `FileInfo` object.  All FileInfo does is provide methods to move, copy, delete or open the files.  From the code you have it doesn't look like you need it.

Answer (score 1):

When populating the listbox, use the filename instead instead the FileInfo
Then when in Button1_Click, use `ListBox1.SelectedValue` to get the selected file name

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox2.Items.Clear();
        if (ListBox1.SelectedIndex > -1)
        {
            string filename = ListBox1.SelectedValue;

            StreamReader FileRead = new StreamReader(filename);
            string CurrentLine = "";
            //int LineCount = 0;
            while (FileRead.Peek() != -1)
            {
                CurrentLine = FileRead.ReadLine();
                ListBox2.Items.Add(CurrentLine);
            }
            FileRead.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            ListBox2.Items.Add("Please select a file first");
        }
    }

    protected void Btn_Load_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\errorlog");
        FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.txt");
        foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
        {
            ListBox1.Items.Add(file.FullName);

        }
    }
```

}

Comment: How do you know it's an ASP.NET app??

Comment: I assumed it because the error he mentionned specified 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem'

Comment: i have two list box in one i showed list of files from one directory in another i have to show slected text files from listbox 1.following code is for listbox 1 its working fine.               protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

Comment: the foolowing code did not give error but shows compilation error on filename.

Comment: no,this is not homework assienment. first i have to do this for my system so that latr i can use this to fetch for remote server , i am a trainee i dint have much knowledge as you guys..

Comment: filename cannot read the value from selected list..you have any idea..@Eric Beaulieu

Comment: @user2533029 I do not understand, is "filename cannot read the value from selected list" an error you are getting?